# Django does not Override Settings in Template Tag Testing

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

Well, I haven't been getting some answers or commentary partly because the codes in the original content below is so restricted to their own small contexts, so instead of that, I wanted to share the whole codebase with you (don't worry, I will permalink the selected lines) because I intend to open the source anyway so that you can review as much as you'd like to.

The whole codebase is [here](https://github.com/erayerdin/django-persistent-settings/tree/perma/1). It's `perma/1` branch of the repository.

## Original Content

I have a custom template tag as below:

```py
# other imports
from django.conf import settings

DPS_TEMPLATE_TRUE_DEFAULT = getattr(settings, "DPS_TEMPLATE_TRUE_DEFAULT", "True")


@register.simple_tag(name="var")
def get_var(name, rit=DPS_TEMPLATE_TRUE_DEFAULT, rif="False", rin=""):
    """
    A template tag to render value of a variable.
    """

    _LOGGER.debug("Rendering value for `%s`...", name)

    variable = models.Variable.objects.get(name=name)
    value = variable.value

    if value is None:
        return rin

    if isinstance(value, bool):
        if value:
            return rit
        else:
            return rif

    return variable.value
```

As you can see, I would like to set `rit` by `DPS_TEMPLATE_TRUE_DEFAULT`. I test this behavior as below:

```py
# `template_factory` and `context_factory` creates Template and Context instances accordingly.
# i use them in other tests. they work.

    @pytest.mark.it("Render if True by settings")
    def test_render_if_true_settings(
        self, template_factory, context_factory, variable_factory, settings
    ):
        settings.DPS_TEMPLATE_TRUE_DEFAULT = "this is true by settings"
        variable_factory(True)
        template = template_factory("FOO", tag_name=self.tag_name).render(
            context_factory()
        )
        assert "<p>this is true by settings</p>" in template
```

I use `pytest-django` and, as [the docs put](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#settings), I can *kinda* mock the settings. However, when I run the test, it does not see `DPS_TEMPLATE_TRUE_DEFAULT` and uses `"True"`. I debugged this behavior by removing `"True"` on `getattr`.

Why does it not see `DPS_TEMPLATE_TRUE_DEFAULT` even if I set it in tests?

## Addition / New Content

[In the custom template tag](https://github.com/erayerdin/django-persistent-settings/blob/perma/1/persistent_settings/templatetags/persistent_settings.py#L10), you can see that I'd like to grab `DPS_TEMPLATE_TRUE_DEFAULT` from `django.conf.settings` and use it as `rit` kwarg in my `var` tag.

[This](https://github.com/erayerdin/django-persistent-settings/blob/perma/1/project/tests/test_templatetags.py#L43-L52) is where I test this behavior by mutating the related setting with `settings` fixture of `pytest-django` and [it fails](https://github.com/erayerdin/django-persistent-settings/runs/344509377#step:5:28).

As the troubleshooting section states I have also tried the other and possibly official ways to do this, they produce the same behavior. As to why it does that, I have no clue.

## Troubleshooting

### Using Standard Solutions

The odd thing is I have also tried good-old `django.test.utils.override_settings` and `modify_settings`, which show the same behavior.

### Eager Initialization

I thought, maybe, the problem was I was using `getattr` outside the scope of `get_var` function, which would load it before it executes, which means before the tests and *somehow* does not let me set it again. So I moved `getattr` inside `get_var` function but the behavior was the same. It behaves like `DPS_TEMPLATE_TRUE_DEFAULT` does not exist in settings.

### Hardcoding into Settings File

So I have hardcoded the "failing to see" setting in the `settings.py` file as below:

```py
DPS_TEMPLATE_TRUE_DEFAULT = "this is true by settings"
```

Still it behaves like `DPS_TEMPLATE_TRUE_DEFAULT` does not exist.

This is also proven by removing the default value `"True"` from `getattr` [in this line](https://github.com/erayerdin/django-persistent-settings/blob/perma/1/persistent_settings/templatetags/persistent_settings.py#L10).

---

## Environment

- Django 2.2.8
- Pytest Django 3.7.0

Comment: Could it be due to how pytest overrides the settings? You can test that by using settings.DPS_TEMPLATE_TRUE_DEFAULT in `get_attr`. If that is the case, then you could catch the attribute error in the case it's not set. Or add a default value of None for `DPS_TEMPLATE_TRUE_DEFAULT`.

Comment: I will consider it but I do not think so because I have also already tried to use `override_settings` of Django.